# How to get response from a Route in Apache Camel inside a Processor and call that Route inside processor?

Tags: java, apache-camel

How to get response from a Route in Apache Camel inside a Processor?

Enrich contents from Database 1 and create Employee List.

Now for each employee call database 2 but want to do the same in processor.

```
         from("direct:processOrder").id("dd")

                .log(LoggingLevel.INFO, getEmployeeCall())
                .setBody(constant(getEmployeeCall()))
                .to("jdbc:masterdata?outputClass=com.evry.integrator.Employee")
                .to("log:?level=INFO&showBody=true")                    
                .process(new IfsProcessor())
                .end();

public class IfsProcessor implements Processor{

   @Override
  public void process(Exchange exchange) throws Exception {
    List<Employee> eiEmployees = (List<Employee>) exchange.getIn().getBody(List.class);

    for (Employee employee : eiEmployees) {
```

I am not able to create ROute inside IfsProcessor which means i need to make it in main class and call it from here?

also i want to call another DB for each employee and want it to return response so that i can update employee object.

How is it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I wrote in [my answer to your other question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60560984/8035582), the problem arise because you do most of the work inside a `Processor` (plain Java) instead of the Camel route.